# Binding a database view to a c# .net gridview

Tags: sql, gridview, view

I have been using excel to view the database tables by binding the sql database views in excel and making a spreadsheet. This works just fine but I want a solution in code.

Is there a way in C# ASP.NET to bind a database view directly to a gridview when given the view name as a string?

******SOLVED************

I did some more research and found a solution. The main issue was that I didn't want to have to make any business objects or have a stored procedure on my database.

The solution I found was to use an SqlDataSource. I simply set the SqlDataSource.ConnectionString and set the SqlDataSource.SelectCommand to be "Select * From" +MyViewName and then bind the datasource to the gridview.

Using this method I essentially just have to pass in the table/view name and the gridview will be populated from the database directly. This allows me to use the same code and the only thing that needs changing is the database view name string.

Comment: why not you directly querry with Excel to bind with gridview